# Install Php 7.4.1, oracleclient and oci8 in CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Tags: php, linux, centos7, oci8, oracleclient

I am trying to install PHP 7.4.1, oracleclient and oci8 for oracle connectivity. I have tried with every possible solutions on various forums but no luck.
System: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa|grep php
php-common-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64
php-process-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-opcache-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-xml-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-devel-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-sodium-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pdo-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pear-1.10.12-2.el7.remi.noarch
php-cli-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-json-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-gd-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-oci8-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-fedora-autoloader-1.0.1-2.el7.noarch
php-7.4.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]# 


[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa|grep oracle
oracle-instantclient18.3-sqlplus-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64
oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64
oracle-instantclient18.3-jdbc-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64
oracle-instantclient18.3-devel-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]#
```

[root@localhost ~]# vi .bash_profile

## .bash_profile

## Get the aliases and functions

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi

## User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi .bashrc vi .bashrc
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64
export ORACLE_HOME




[root@localhost ~]# vi .bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64
export ORACLE_HOME
```

I am very beginner in system. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Using my repository, you need latest Oracle Client Library version **19.8** (not 18.3)

```
$ rpm -qi php-oci8
...
The php-oci8 packages provides the OCI8 extension version 2.2.0
and the PDO driver to access Oracle Database.

The extension is linked with Oracle client libraries 19.8
(Oracle Instant Client).  For details, see Oracle's note
"Oracle Client / Server Interoperability Support" (ID 207303.1).

You must install libclntsh.so.19.1 to use this package, provided
in the database installation, or in the free Oracle Instant Client
available from Oracle.
...
```

This is explained in detail in [Installation of Oracle extensions for PHP](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP)